# Android service is not started from Unity

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine, android-service

I'm developing an android app with Unity that requires a foreground service. To do that I've made an android module with android studio. The problem is that my service is never started but at the same time there aren't errors and the aplication still running, for example after my start service I can show a toast.

**Unity - C# - AndroidPluginManager.cs**

I'm using this class to instantiate the module and call the function to start the service. The function StartAndroidService() is called using the onClick() feature of Unity inspector.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AndroidPluginManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    private AndroidJavaObject androidPlugin = null;
    private AndroidJavaObject unityContext = null;
    private AndroidJavaObject unityActivity = null;
    private AndroidJavaClass unityClass = null;

    void Start() {

        //Get unity activity and context
        unityClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");   
        unityActivity = unityClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
        unityContext = unityActivity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getApplicationContext");

        //Create android plugin object
        androidPlugin = new AndroidJavaObject("com.androidplugin.stepcounterlibrary.ApiStepCounter");

        //Set activity and context to the module 
        androidPlugin.Call("setActivity", unityActivity);
        androidPlugin.Call("setContext", unityContext);
    }

    //Start Service
    public void StartAndroidService() {

        androidPlugin.Call("startStepCounter");
        androidPlugin.Call("showMessage", "Hello World");

    }
}
```

**Android Studio - Java - ApiStepCounter.java**

For the time being I'm using this class only to start the service and create a toast to check if the module is working correctly.

```
package com.androidplugin.stepcounterlibrary;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ApiStepCounter{

    private Activity activity;
    private Context context;

    public ApiStepCounter() {}

    public void setActivity(Activity activity){
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public void setContext(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void showMessage(String message){
        Toast.makeText(this.context, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void startStepCounter(){

        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this.context, StepCounterService.class);
        this.context.startService(serviceIntent);
    }
}
```

**Android Studio - Java - StepCounterService.java**

This class should start the foreground service and show a notification but it doesn't. It's the first time that I try to use an Android service so I don't know if I'm doing something wrong. Also I've tried to execute some Log.d inside each method (onCreate(), onStartCommand(), onDestroy()) and no one is printed so I guess that the service is not started.

```
package com.androidplugin.stepcounterlibrary;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;

import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class StepCounterService extends Service {


    public StepCounterService(){}

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "TestChannel");
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_android)
                .setContentText("Text of notification")
                .setContentTitle("Title of notification");

        Notification notification = builder.build();

        startForeground(1, notification);

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
       return  null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

**Android Studio - Manifest - AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.androidplugin.stepcounterlibrary">    
    <application>
        <service android:name=".StepCounterService"/>
    </application>    
</manifest>
```

I've been trying for 2 days how to create the foreground service using Unity with an Android module so if someone could help me I would appreciate it a lot. Feel free to ask me anything  that you need, I think this is all that I need to create a foreground service but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: What you receive call in startStepCounter()? from Unity to Android